# Obtener acceso a oracle

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Quienes entiendan de Oracle... Hay formas de recuperar la contraseña de la base de datos?
Tenemos un sistema que trabaja con Oracle pero ahora hemos decidido cambiar el sistema y no tenemos acceso a la base de datos debido a que el que hizo el sistema no nos proporciono la contraseña de administración y estamos necesitando migrar los datos que hay en ellos... Hay alguna forma de recuperar la contraseña? Si alguien ha tenido un caso igual?

Comment: La primera opción es **ponerse en contacto con la persona que hizo el sistema**, lo ha considerado?

Comment: Ese es el principal problema... La persona que hizo el sistema desaparecio totalmente... Debió haber entregado las claves pero no lo hizo... Nos dejó su número de teléfono pero no contesta hace bastante tiempo... Ya no es una posibilidad por eso hice esta pregunta a los que entienden de Oracle...

Answer (score 1):

Para poder recuperar la contraseña de la BD de Oracle, requerirás acceso al Sistema Operativo en donde esta instalada la BD.

Una vez dentro debes realizar lo siguiente:

1. Iniciar la BD como sysdba. Desde CMD en Windows o una Terminal en Linux. Deberas tener correctamente cargadas las variables de ambiente para que el comando "sqlplus" sea reconocido.

> $ sqlplus "/ as sysdba"

2. Modificar la contraseña del esquema deseado (en este ejemplo se cambia la contraseña del usuario system)

> SQL> passw system

3. Salir

> SQL> quit

Comment: Muchas gracias lo voy a intentar

Comment: Tuviste oportunidad de intentar la recuperación del usuario?

Comment: Si muchas gracias... Lo intente y recupere la base de datos... Por tiempo no respondí enceguida pero funcionó...

Comment: Excelente que hayas recuperado tu BD. Saludos!